# MongoDB - simple sub query example

Tags: mongodb, nested, subquery, pymongo

Given the data:

```
> db.parameters.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cac0cd0b5a1ffab1bd6c12"), "name" : "Speed", "groups" : [ "
123", "234" ] }
> db.groups.find({})
{ "_id" : "123", "name" : "Group01" }
{ "_id" : "234", "name" : "Group02" }
{ "_id" : "567", "name" : "Group03" }
```

I would like to supply a *parameter* _id an make a query return all groups that are within the *groups* array of the given document in *parameters* table.

The straightforward solution seems to make several DB calls in PyMongo:

1. Get parameter from *parameters* table based on the supplied _id
2. For each element of *groups* array select a document from *groups* collection

But this will have so much unnecessary overhead. I feel there must be a better, faster way to do this within MongoDB (without running custom JS in the DB). Or should I re-structure my data by normalising it a little bit (like a table of relationships), neglecting the document-based approach?

Again, please help me find a solution that would work from PyMongo DB interface

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this within a single query using the aggregation framework. In particular you'd need to run an aggregation pipeline that uses the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator to do a left join from the `parameters` collection to the `groups` collection.

Consider running the following pipeline:

```
db.parameters.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$groups" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "groups",
            "localField": "groups",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "grp"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$grp" }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cac0cd0b5a1ffab1bd6c12"),
    "name" : "Speed",
    "groups" : "123",
    "grp" : {
        "_id" : "123",
        "name" : "Group01"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cac0cd0b5a1ffab1bd6c12"),
    "name" : "Speed",
    "groups" : "234",
    "grp" : {
        "_id" : "234",
        "name" : "Group02"
    }
}
```

---

If your MongoDB server version does not support the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline operator, then you'd need execute two queries as follows:

```
# get the group ids
ids = db.parameters.find_one({ "_id": ObjectId("56cac0cd0b5a1ffab1bd6c12") })["groups"]

# query the groups collection with the ids from previous query
db.groups.find({ "_id": { "$in": ids } })
```

EDIT: matched the field name in the aggregation query to the field name in example dataset (within the question)

Comment: How would you do a right join? Or, how would you swap the collections left and right if you still need to unwind the one on the right?

Comment: What about an inner join?