# How to nested sql select in Spring Data mongoTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In SQL, we will have nested selects.

```
Select * from Book where bookId in 
  (select bookId from borrower where borrowerid in 
     (select borrowerId from library where libraryId=1))
```

This is a very normal use case where we are going to have multiple select. This is one db call. For mongoTemplate, I have 3 Criterias for each select and now it is making 3 db calls. This is not ideal for sure, but works as a temporary solution.

My question is how to do this in mongoTemplate with 1 db call?

Comment: do you mean MySQL or JPA?

Comment: I need to use MongoTemplate

Comment: you "can't", mongo works differently than mysql but here's a start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304211/mongodb-simple-sub-query-example

Comment: Either change the schema to better for the document model of MongoDB or make an Aggregation with $lookup steps https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
The former is usually the way to go, and if it isn't a good fit for MongoDB, don't force it and stay with a relational DB ;)